# Generate a class of matrices via optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

I want to generate a matrix (using Matlab) with the following properties:

(1) $A = (a_{ij}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$;

(2) $a_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$ and $a_{ii} = 0$ for all $i\in\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$;

(3) $A {\bf 1} = A^T {\bf 1}$ where ${\bf 1} = [1,1,\cdots,1]^T \in \mathbb{R}^n$

any hints or how to find the feasible $A$ under a optimization formulation, thanks!